# Create a loopable container class in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to clean up my code a bit and make it more similar to the Excel object model, and I was wondering if it is possible to create a "loopable" container class in VBA, e.g. similar to how you can do:

```
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   ' ...
Next Sheet
```

I want this functionality for my own container.

Say I create my own class called `Container` which contains items of some class `ItemType` (this can simply be an empty class for this example):

```
' Class Container
' The container contains items of a class I will call ItemType

Private Type MContainer
  Items As Collection ' Could also be implemented in terms of an array
End Type

Private This As MContainer

Public Property Get Item(ByVal Index As Long) As ItemType
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0 'Makes it so I can access elements like a Collection
  Set Item = This.Items(Index)
End Property

Public Function Add() As ItemType
  This.Items.Add
  Set Add = This.Items(This.Items.Count)
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set This.Items = New Collection
End Sub
```

I then want to loop through the items in my container with the `For Each...`, but this doesn't work. See the following example for how I ideally want it to work:

```
Public Sub MyMethod()

  Dim Stuff As New Container
  Stuff.Add

  Dim Element As ItemType
  For Each Element In Stuff ' <- This will not work
    ' Do something
  Next Element

End Sub
```

The final `For` loop is what I am looking at making work. Is this possible? Basically the issue is that I can't call `For Each` on my `Container` class similar to how you can with e.g. the `Excel.Sheets` class. Is this possible to achieve in VBA?

Comment: you are missing the Enumeration implementation on your collection i.e Items

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]? Current code examples you have won't compile

Comment: @DavidZemens Isn't it a bit hard to provide compiling code for VBA? The only thing I see that you need to compile this is an empty class file with the name `ItemType`. Except obviously the last code snippet which I provided as an example for what I want to get compiling, but doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your class

```
Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = Items .[_NewEnum]
End Function
```

Comment: Note that you need to add the `Attribute` outside the VBA IDE; export your class module, open with any editor, add the `Attribute` line (or the whole function), save the file and import it to your Workbook.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Would it be possible to get some sort of explanation? This seems like black magic to me. Does the function name have to be NewEnum or is it the attribute flag that marks it? Would it be possible to name it `_NewEnum` like the collection to hide it? How is `NewEnum` defined, i.e. what would I do if I was using an array as a container?

Comment: @JonasGlesaaen arrays are best iterated with a `For...Next` loop though. `For Each` iteration over an array is inefficient... doing that would essentially defeat the performance benefits of an object enumerator.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the info, however, it would be instructive to just understand what `NewEnum` expects if I didn't have the `Collections` class to use. I.e. how would I implement it myself if I had written a container from scratch.

Comment: @JonasGlesaaen agreed! ...problem is, that's hardly documented at all :(

Answer (score 4):

`For Each` iteration requires a special member attribute value to work, and a `NewEnum` property or function returning an `IUnknown`.

Every collection class that can be iterated with a `For Each` loop has a hidden `[_NewEnum]` member (the square brackets are required for accessing the hidden member, since the underscore prefix is illegal for an identifier in VBA.

Tweaking module and member attributes isn't possible to do directly in the VBE, so you need to remove/export the module, modify it in e.g. Notepad++, save the changes, then re-import it into your project.

Or, have [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (disclaimer: I contribute to this open-source project) do it for you, using annotations (aka "magic comments"):

```
'@Enumerator
'@Description("Gets an enumerator that iterates through the internal object collection.")
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = this.Items.[_NewEnum]
End Function

'@DefaultMember
'@Description("Gets/sets the element at the specified index.")
Public Property Get Item(ByVal index As Long) As ItemType
    Set Item = this.Items(index)
End Property
```

Then parse the project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>) and bring up the *Inspection Results* toolwindow (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) - there should be a number of "Missing Attribute" results under "Rubberduck Opportunities":

[image: inspection results]

Click "Fix all occurrences in module" in the bottom pane, to synchronize the hidden attributes with the annotation comments.

If you have "Missing Annotation" results, Rubberduck has determined that a module/member has a non-default value for a given attribute, and is able to similarly add an annotation comment that surfaces/documents it with a comment.

The *Code Explorer* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), the Rubberduck toolbar, and the VBE's own *Object Browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd>) will display the contents of the `VB_Description` attribute, so `@Description` annotations are particularly useful to have on any public procedure.

Object Browser:

[image: Object Browser showing member description]

Code Explorer:

[image: Code Explorer showing member description]

Rubberduck toolbar:

[image: RD toolbar showing member description]

Comment: I am a Rubberduck user myself ^^ And the magic comments are something I didn't know about, at least not the ones you mention here. But they seem super useful as having to export, edit, and import again is a real hassle. Would be great if you could document all of your magic comments somewhere, but that should probably be an issue in your github project ^^

Comment: I have seen that issue, but I understand it as you wanting to add this directly into Rubberduck, which is great, but I would be more than content with a simple wiki page telling me what exists :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to this issue is not to use a Collection but a Scripting.Dictionary.  One of the advantages of a scripting dictionary is that it can return arrays of the keys and items of the dictionary.  Iterating over an array in VBA is a trivial exercise.