# Creating hidden class members and member functions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen that you can create "hidden" things in VBA by prefixing their names with an underscore (or possibly some other illegal first character). By hidden I do not mean private, but I mean a public thing that will not appear in VBE autocomplete; you have to know of its existence if you want to use it.

Some recent examples I have seen is:

The `_NewEnum` function in the `Collection` class (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402347/create-a-loopable-container-class-in-vba) question), and I quite often create `Enum` like this:

```
Public Enum SomeEnumeration
  [_First]
  FirstCategory = [_First]
  SecondCategory
  ThirdCategory
  [_Last] = ThirdCategory
  [_Invalid] = [_Last] + 1
End Enum
```

Because this allows me to loop through my enumeration without adding additional exposed categories, which would confuse things.

My question is this: Is it possible to use this construct for other things than enumerations? I see that `Container` is able to do it, but can I do this myself. I.e., how would I write a class module with a hidden function:

```
' Class module SomeClass

' Illustration of what I want, but this will not compile
Public Function _Hidden() As Variant
  ' Return something
End Function
```

And then access this function through

```
Dim Obj As New SomeClass
Obj.[_Hidden] ' This option should not be visible in the VBE autocomplete
```

I have tried defining the function with surrounding `[]`, but that also doesn't work.

This would be useful because I quite often use default instances of classes as object factories as a workaround for the fact that the VBA class constructor doesn't accept any arguments. However, when you do that you run into issues where you have to expose certain parts of your class that should in reality be private and set in the constructor. If I could name these things something hidden it would make my interfaces cleaner, and prevent accidental usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default instance of a class as a factory with create and self functions then you may also wish to consider using an interface as the arbiter of which functions are private and which are public.  e.g. rather than using the normal I class naming convention for interfaces you have 'Classprivate' which is the class definition and 'Class' which is the interface.  There is no intention to have the interface for multiple related objects, just as a public/private filter.

This has a number of advantages.

1. You can make all methods and properties of the class public which greatly facilitates unit testing.
2. The factory only returns the interface object so there is no confusion as to whether you are using the class instance or interface.

The Rubberduck addin for VBA makes the creation of interfaces almost trivial.